# Number of permutations of length $n$ with constraints on number of repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a nice formula for the number of permutations of $n$ characters such that each character repeats *at most* $k$ times? For $k=1$ this is $n!$, for $k=n$ this is $n^n$, and in general, this can be expressed as a sum of multinomials - I am wondering specifically about some closed forms, or asymptotics.

In general, let $K_n(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ denote the number of permutations of length $n$ with repetition such that the $i$th character is repeated at most $a_i$ times. Is there a nice expression for $\frac{K_{n-1}(a_1 - 1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)}{K_n(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)}$?

Comment: I don't think "permutation" is the right word to use here. Do you mean strings of length $n$ consisting of (up to) $n$ distinct characters?

Comment: @kccu Yes. I've seen this called "permutation with repetition" before